# single tone -> multi bandpass filter -> incorrect output

Tags: filter-design, filtering, bandpass

**background**:
Trying to filter out all other signal frequencies except -> signal whose frequency can be in multiple's of 16Hz {16,32,48.......160].

so started experimenting with a single tone [no noise] at 16 Hz and i get weird output spectrum.

**Input**: single tone waveform at 16Hz.
[image]

[image]
**Filter**: multi-bandpass filter design using [kaiserord](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/kaiserord.html)

**output** [image]

**Issue**:
I followed Mathworks page of kaiserord and also this [example](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/503999-filtering-for-multiple-band-of-frequncies), however the output is not expected. No noise added, just plain $e^{j2\pi ft}$ with $f=16$ fed into this kaiserord filter and I get the weird spectrum.
Code uses `signal_filtered = filtfilt(hh, 1, input_signal)`;

**question**:
Filter design looks correct and so is input signal.
Is there anything wrong in my approach/design? please teach me if I am missing anything obvious or overlooked anything?

Comment: 1. Are you sure your input signal is correctly synthesized? Maybe add the code used to synthesize it to your question.  2. Use a real input (replace exp() with sin())

Comment: Please post your entire code. We can't tell by you words and a few snippets what exactly is happening.

Comment: I uploaded the code at https://pastebin.com/ES6MSzJU